# Rally App SDK using TreeView to load testfolders, only loads top folder

Tags: rally

Trying to run the treeview examples provided for Rally App SDK testfolders example [here] [1] -  https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.tree.Tree [1]

Tried the examples provided for usestory and test folders both loads only the top level, does not load the child tasks/user stories in case of userstory & for test folders does not load the child folders or test cases.

Here is the extract from App.js file.

```js
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    
    launch: function() {
     
     this.add({
             xtype: 'rallytree',
             topLevelModel: Ext.identityFn('TestFolder'),
             childModelTypeForRecordFn: function(record){
                 if(record.get('Children') && record.get('Children').length > 0){
                     return 'TestFolder';
                 } else {
                     return 'TestCase';
                 }
             },
             givenAParentRecordWhatIsTheAttributeConnectingAChildToThisParentFn: function(record){
                 if(record.get('Children') && record.get('Children').length > 0){
                     return 'Parent';
                 } else {
                     return 'TestFolder';
                 }
             },
             canExpandFn: function(record){
                 return record.get('Children') && record.get('Children').length > 0
                 || record.get('TestCases') && record.get('TestCases').length > 0;
             },
             enableDragAndDrop: false,
             dragThisGroupOnMeFn: function(record){
                 if(record.get('_type') === 'testfolder'){
                     if(record.get('Children') && record.get('Children').length > 0){
                         return 'testfolder';
                     }
                     if(record.get('TestCases') && record.get('TestCases').length > 0){
                         return 'testcase';
                     }
                     return ['testfolder', 'testcase'];
                 }
             },
             topLevelStoreConfig: {
                 sorters: []
             },
             childItemsStoreConfigForParentRecordFn: function(){
                 return {
                     sorters: []
                 };
             }
                //remaining config omitted for brevity
            
        /**/
      });
        //API Docs: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this app:
https://github.com/nikantonelli/TestCaseOrganiser

That should show your TestFolder hierarchy and test cases beneath them and even allow drag and drop moving of test cases.